# Rough Idle On 1997 Dodge Dakota

Tags: starting

So my Dodge is a v6 and sometimes when I start the engine the RPMS Drop, sometimes all the way to zero or about 500. It recently started to do this maybe a week ago and I don't know what it could be I've searched everywhere and it seems to me nobody has the same problem I'm having, could I get some help or ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at the idle control valve

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is the idle speed, a mechanic with experience in your car model can easily adjust the idle speed, and it should stay at the proper speed, but since it is not a permanent issue the common reasons for this to happen are the following:

1. vacuum leak
2. Dirty Fuel Injectors
3. Incorrectly Installed or Damaged Plugs
4. Defective or Clogged Fuel Pump
5. Clogged Fuel Filter

If you are looking to fix the car by yourself start with inspecting the pipe for air leaks.